# How to concat string in LinQ group

Tags: c#, linq

```
var list = Table
    .GroupBy(t => t.GroupId, (key, g) => new {key, g})
    .Select(t => new Transaction
    {
        Date = t.g.First().DateCreate,
        Reference = $"{t.g.First().AccounttName} {t.g.Select(z => z.DocumentNo)}",
        TotalAmount = t.g.Sum(x => x.y.Amount.Value),
    })
```

When grouping with linQ I know how to get a single value with First(), sum with Sum() but what should I do to concact a string value?

In my example how can I merge all my DocumentNo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Reference = $"{t.g.First().AccounttName} {string.Join(",",t.g.Select(z => z.DocumentNo))}"
```

Comment: Ah... Join... Thank you. Do you know why string.Concat is not working?

Comment: [`string.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd(v=vs.110).aspx) concatenates **two** strings. Here you need to join together a *list* of strings

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Not really - there are other `Concat` [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx) which accept multiple strings (for instance the first in the list). `Concat` should work in the general case (LINQ to Objects). But the error message indicates usage of another (not specified) query provider, hence the question lacks context. It really depends on what CLR methods are supported by the concrete query provider.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes you're right ofcourse. Should've checked the various overloads... I Was not aware that there were so many overloads for the `Concat`.